# Git merge error caused by visual studio after checking out to master branch

Tags: git, github, merge, gitlab, git-flow

Im pretty new to git and i still couldn't figure out the best approach, when it comes to flow of git.

Im using this flow, but it seems to cause errors. Could you fix it for me?

```
->git clone [repo name]
->cd [repo name]
->git status
*On branch master nothing to commit
->git checkout -b "class-lib-move"
->start [project name].sln (openning code in visual studio)
Making some changes...
->git add .
->git commit -m "changes ..."
->git checkout master
->git merge class-lib-move
*error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        .vs/VideoToText/v17/.suo
        /obj/Debug/net6.0/VideoToText.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig
        VideoToText/obj/Debug/net7.0/VideoToText.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig
        VideoToText/obj/Debug/net7.0/VideoToText.assets.cache
        VideoToText/obj/VideoToText.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
        VideoToText/obj/VideoToText.csproj.nuget.g.props
        VideoToText/obj/project.assets.json
        VideoToText/obj/project.nuget.cache
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
->git add .
->git commit -m "useless commit"
->git merge class-lib-move
->git status

warning: Cannot merge binary files: .vs/VideoToText/v17/.suo (HEAD vs. class-lib-move)
Auto-merging .vs/VideoToText/v17/.suo
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .vs/VideoToText/v17/.suo
Auto-merging VideoToText/obj/VideoToText.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in VideoToText/obj/VideoToText.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
Auto-merging VideoToText/obj/project.assets.json
Auto-merging VideoToText/obj/project.nuget.cache
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in VideoToText/obj/project.nuget.cache
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

And there goes my flow. I only see an option to upload the feature branch to remote, completely delete the folder,git clone repo again and and finaly merging it. Am i missing something out?

Problem seems to be caused by visual studio. In the moment im switching branch to master, it overwriting some files by itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your keep too much stuff in the repository. For example, the `.vs` directory need not be under version control, nor should be the build artefacts and generated files such as `obj/Debug/`, nor (most likely) stuff in any `*.cache` file or directory.

When you set up the repository, you should have created a `.gitignore` file that listed everything that is not source code, so that `git add .` would not have added these files to the repository.

Fixing this after the fact is possible, but is going to cause a tremendous headache for anybody who has also cloned the repository (instructions are basically to `git rm --cached the_unwanted_files` after you have added `the_unwanted_files` to `.gitignore`).

My alternative recommendation is: if you can, start with a new repository.